# Coating gone wrong

Tags: finishing

I have a large piece of Camphor Laurel that I have sanded and given a sealing coat to. I'm using Bonball Marine Varnish. I have left it between coats for 24 hours. This is the 3rd full coat today and to my horror, it has gone funny. Not cloudy but like its separated and got streaks in it. It's over the whole top.. What should I do and what caused this to happen?? it's only 21c here today and a slight breeze.. So I would not have thought to hot plus this is the same weather it has been the last few days. So disappointed. Many thanks for any help.

Comment: 21°C is more than warm enough for good results when varnishing so it's unlikely to be the temp. Without pics I'm really guessing what might have gone wrong here but it's possible some contaminant got on the second coat that caused this to happen.

Comment: If you asked soon enough and I'm replying fast enough, so the varnish in coat no. 3 hasn't had a chance to cure too much, you may be able to soften and remove it with white spirit/mineral spirits or paint thinner and lots of paper towels or cotton rags. This may or may not damage the varnish underneath which has had a chance to dry more, but you lose nothing trying it since other remedies involve removing some or all of it anyway.

Comment: Thank you , It's too late for that. Im thinking, as I am limited to using a brush maybe I should start again with a different product. Maybe a water based polyurethane floor finish?? Its disheartening when you are trying to follow the instructions and it goes funny. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: You should be able to salvage what you have as it sounds like it's only the surface that has gone odd. You just need to sand back a bit, then apply a fresh coat of varnish. I would recommend you transfer a bit of the Bonball (if necessary just spoon the varnish out) to a jar with a tight-fitting lid so you can thin it slight, by about 10-15% is sufficient although you can go thinner if you like. Varnish does build more slowly after it has been diluted but the thinner consistency helps in lots of ways.

Comment: I will try that then. Is mineral turps OK to use to thin with? Many thanks ...

Comment: I think that's the right stuff, is that the Australian name for white spirit? Either way the appropriate solvent will be the one listed on the tin of varnish (or any other oil-based paint or varnish) for cleaning brushes.

Comment: I think that's the right stuff, is that the Australian name for white spirit? Either way the appropriate solvent will be the one listed on the tin of varnish (or any other oil-based paint or varnish) for cleaning brushes.

Comment: Yes, I am in Oz LOL.... I do forget this is a big world, thank you so much for your help. i was going to put a photo on, but unsure how to go about that , Cheers ..